# Contributing to Roth IRA at beginning of year

Tags: united-states, roth-ira

I plan to contribute the maximum $6000 to my Roth IRA for 2019 in the next month. **However**, there is a good possibility I will make over $122,000 dollars with overtime and therefore will be disqualified from contributing.

**What happens if I do make over $122,000?** Do I have to take the money out?

Comment: Did you already contribute the maximum for 2018? You can make your 2018 contribution up until the April tax deadline.

Comment: @HartCO Yes, maxed for 2017, 2018.

Comment: Does your employer offer a 401k? If so, contributing to one will reduce your Modified Adjusted Gross Income, or MAGI. Keep in mind that the $122,000 limit applies to your MAGI, not your gross salary. Example: you earn $140,000 and contribute the 2019 max of $19000 to your 401k. Your MAGI would be $121,000, making you eligible for the full Roth contribution.

Answer (score 4):

That may be the simplest option, but there are others.

from non-authoritative source [RothIRA.com](https://www.rothira.com/blog/what-to-do-if-you-contribute-too-much-to-your-roth-ira):

> ### Recharacterize Your Contribution
>
> Ideally you would be able to recharacterize your extra contributions
>   and any NIA into a Traditional IRA. “Recharacterize” means essentially
>   “I don’t want these to go toward a Roth, I want them to go to a
>   Traditional IRA.” This also assumes you would qualify to contribute to
>   a Traditional IRA for that tax year. This is ideal because you’re
>   still saving for retirement.
>
> ### Withdraw Your Contribution Overage
>
> If you don’t qualify for a Traditional IRA (and thus cannot
>   recharacterize your overage), you can simply withdraw the extra
>   contribution and any NIA (income earned by the excess contributions).
>
> ### Apply Your Contribution to a Future Year
>
> You can also apply the excess contribution and NIA to a future year.
>   You may have to pay a 6 percent tax to the IRS to be able to do this.

Comment: Almost everyone with _compensation_ is entitled to _contribute_ to a Traditional IRA; the disqualification that you refer to is for _deducting_ the Traditional IRA contribution -- said _deduction not being allowed for high earners.  Since the OP is already committing to contributing the maximum amount to a  _Roth_ IRA (which provides for no deductions from taxable income for the contribution), just recharacterizing the contribution as a nondeductible contribution to a Traditional IRA is no skin off his nose.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer this method because **there are no decision points** based on income.  However, it depends on not having any existing traditional IRAs or converting them to Roth first.

### Contribute to a Traditional IRA...

There are no income limits for this.  Do this at the same institution where you keep your Roth.  Invest the money in a cash sweep account, do not put it in anything interest bearing, and especially, not in a bond or stock.

There are income limits for *taking the tax deduction*, but that matters not, since you don't want to do that. That makes it a Non-Deductible IRA, and the amount of your contribution will not be taxed when it comes back out, since you already did pay taxes on it.  Gains would be taxable, so we're avoiding gains by putting it in a cash sweep account.

### ... Then, convert to Roth

The very next day, convert the amount in the traditional IRA to Roth.   *There is no income limit on this either*.

There is also no tax, because you are converting money you "already paid taxes on".

Normally, when you convert to Roth, you must treat the converted amount as taxable income, and normally you would aim to do this in a gap year.  However, since you are converting from a *non-deductible traditional IRA*, there is no tax on the amount you contributed (yesterday).

Together these two are the "Roth backdoor" and can be done at any income level (provided your taxable income >= the contribution.)

Comment: Since the strategy you mention, called a "backdoor roth" this is clearly doing an end run around the income limits for Roth Contributions, there is some concern that if the conversion is done immediately after the contribution, that the whole thing could be disqualified. Legal experts commonly recommend letting them settle for some time.  Also **ALL*** of your tradional and IRA rollover assets are considered when calculating the taxable amount for the conversion, so essentially if you have much money in an IRA it would prevent you from using the backdoor roth strategy.

Comment: @T.M. I'd need to see some refs on your first claim, but I wholeheartedly agree with your second, he would need to add the new IRA in with the rest of his traditional IRAs, and apportion the conversion, the paperwork would be a nightmare, better to just convert all traditional IRAs at that point and take the tax hit.  Unless one is expecting to have a gap year anytime soon.  My advice presumes all his IRAs so far are Roth.

Comment: My ref is unfortunately the tax attorney I chatted about the strategy with, but here is the basic idea: https://www.kitces.com/blog/how-to-do-a-backdoor-roth-ira-contribution-while-avoiding-the-ira-aggregation-rule-and-the-step-transaction-doctrine/ and another:https://www.forbes.com/sites/greatspeculations/2017/10/16/factors-to-consider-when-contemplating-a-backdoor-roth-ira/#445b1634f4ca search ahead for step transaction doctrine.

Comment: @T.M.: Not a problem -- step transaction is specifically mentioned as something some advisors brought up but backdoor Roth is now definitely allowed: https://www.forbes.com/sites/jeffreylevine/2018/07/13/irs-unlocks-the-door-for-high-income-savers/#27679ee5326c

Comment: Interesting, that's new. I didn't go read the conference report https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/CRPT-115hrpt466/pdf/CRPT-115hrpt466.pdf they mention in the linked article, but I'll believe them. Also interesting from the linked article is that characterizations are eliminated. I guess I need to keep up more. :)

Comment: "There are income limits for taking the tax deduction" Only if you or your spouse is covered by a retirement plan at work.

Comment: I un-prefer this method because you jump through hoops you may not need to (if you end up falling under the income limit). Also, a single sentence from a webcast is  hardly definitive proof that this will never be ruled as a step transaction. It's not even a private letter ruling, never mind an actual rule encoded in the IRS code.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to put the money into a non-deductible IRA in January 2019 making sure the custodian knows it is for 2019. Then a few days later do a backdoor Roth conversion.

You will have to pay any taxes on the gains while it is in the non-deductible traditional IRA, but that shouldn't be that much.